# Linux packages Where to download complete dependency list

Tags: linux, dependencies, dependency-management

where do I find the list of all dependencies (direct and transitive dependencies) of most popular Linux packages?

I want a complete list (just list) in the form of dependency graphs, for exploration. Is there a downloadable list of all dependencies of most popular Linux packages somewhere?

There are some offline DVD based installations (like Debian/Ubuntu etc).
Is there any tool that extract dependency information for given packages in those DVDs?

I have seen the question below but this is not what I want.
 [Howto list all dependencies of a Package on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627158/howto-list-all-dependencies-of-a-package-on-linux)

thnx

Comment: Why is the linked question not what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `debian` or `ubuntu` you can issue

```
apt-cache show $PACKAGE_NAME
```

You get print a list of all package dependencies using:

```
for pkg in $(dpkg --get-selections | cut -f1) ; do apt-cache depends  "$pkg" ; done
```

Comment: you could use `dpkg --get-selections` to get a list of packages.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the comment. Have added a one-liner ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't want to browse [Ubuntu's package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), I made a little script that saves all the package names and their dependencies to a text file. Needless to say, it takes a while to run.

[Download the script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/166536) or see the source below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#author: @mrmitche_
#name: Build Dependencies List
#description: Lists the dependencies of all packages in apt on linux.

packages=$(apt-cache pkgnames)
declare -a array=($packages)

for pkg in ${array[@]}
do
    apt-cache depends $pkg >>dependencies.txt
    printf "\n" >>dependencies.txt
done
```

Sample output in dependencies.txt:

```
postgresql-plperl-9.0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libperl5.14
  Depends: postgresql-9.0
  Depends: perl
  Replaces: postgresql-contrib-9.0
  Replaces: postgresql-contrib-9.0:i386
  Conflicts: postgresql-plperl-9.0:i386

libc6-xen:i386
  PreDepends: libc6:i386

python-pkginfo-doc
  Depends: libjs-sphinxdoc

mumudvb
  Depends: adduser
  Depends: dvb-apps
  Depends: libc6
  Suggests: dvbtune
  Conflicts: mumudvb:i386

libuuidm-ocaml-dev
  Depends: <ocaml-nox-3.12.1>
    ocaml-nox
  Depends: libc6
  Suggests: ocaml-findlib
  Conflicts: libuuidm-ocaml-dev:i386
```

You could modify the script to format it however you like. Maybe source the packages so they are in alphabetical order.